# Why is my SecurityContextHolder resetting after navigating to the new UI in my vaadin application?

Tags: java, spring, firebase, vaadin, vaadin-flow

My SecurityContextHolder reset after navigating to the new UI or refresh the page in my vaadin application. I have used the Firebase authentication successfully using JavaScript and then I got the token and Firebase user ID using the login method using ClientCallable annotation. Then I set the Authentication by getting the new authentication. after refresh the page or navigating to other view authentication log message is like below,

> Principal : anonymousUser
> Credentials :
> Auth : AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=5E5D572F6FF1ECAF2EC27CD086ACB6F6], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]

Login class :

```
@AnonymousAllowed
@PageTitle("Login")
@Route(value = "login")
@JsModule("./JavaScripts/firebase.js")
public class LoginView extends VerticalLayout implements BeforeEnterObserver{
  private static final String OAUTH_URL = "/oauth2/authorization/google";
  private final FirebaseService firebase;
  public LoginView(FirebaseService firebaseService){
    this.firebase = firebaseService;
    // Header
    Div header = new Div();
    header.setText("Welcome to File Fortress");
    header.getStyle().set("font-size", "24px");
    add(header);

    // Slogan
    Div slogan = new Div();
    slogan.setText("LAN Exam File Transfer System");
    slogan.getStyle().set("font-size", "18px");
    add(slogan);

    // Description
    Div description = new Div();
    description.setText("Login with Your Google Account to Continue");
    description.getStyle().set("font-size", "16px");
    add(description);

    // Login button
    Button loginButton = new Button("Login with Google");
    loginButton.setTooltipText("You Can Sign In to Application using your Google Account");
    loginButton.addClassName("login-button");
    loginButton.addClickListener(event -> {
//     UI.getCurrent().getPage().setLocation(OAUTH_URL);
        UI.getCurrent().getPage().executeJs("ns.googleSignInPopup($0)", this);
    });

    add(loginButton);

    // Styling
    getStyle().set("padding", "20px");
    setAlignItems(FlexComponent.Alignment.CENTER);
}

@Override
public void beforeEnter(BeforeEnterEvent event) {
    if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated())
        UI.getCurrent().navigate(AboutView.class);
}
@ClientCallable
public void login(String token, String uid){
    System.out.println(token);
    User.getInstance().init(uid,token);
    try {
        // Validate the token at Firebase server  first and create
        Authentication authentication = firebase.login(token);
        // Save the authentication to context
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
    } catch (FirebaseAuthException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid token!");
    }
}


}
```

FirebaseService class :

```
@Service
public class FirebaseService {

private FirebaseApp app;
@PostConstruct
void init() {
    try {
        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("serviceAccountKey.json");

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}

public UserRecord findUserByEmail(String username) throws FirebaseAuthException {
    return FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUserByEmail(username);
}

public Authentication login(String token) throws FirebaseAuthException {
    boolean checkRevoked = true;
    FirebaseToken firebaseToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(token, checkRevoked);
    // Note, before important actions, the token should be re-validate,
    // it could be revoked or the user could be removed altogether,
    // during their session

    return new Authentication() {
        @Override
        public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
            Collection<GrantedAuthority> updatedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
            updatedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            return updatedAuthorities;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getCredentials() {
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getDetails() {
            return firebaseToken;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getPrincipal() {
            return firebaseToken.getUid();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isAuthenticated() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return firebaseToken.getName();
        }
    };
}
}
```

I want to Save the authentication to SecurityContextHolder but it has to be the same Authentication until the user is logged out.

```
 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
```